# What automotive connector is this?

Tags: connector, automotive

Does anyone have an idea what connector this is? It is an automotive connector but unfortunately the numbers on it do not reveal the type. Is this a logo next to the number?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you search "pa66-gf30 69176" on google, lots of these things show up. Good luck.

Comment: PA66 is the plastic type. GF30 is 30 % glass filling.

Comment: Oh boy. That's an automotive connector. They are a challenge.

Ask these guys: https://connectorexperts.com/ or these guys: https://www.automotiveconnectors.com/

Or, go to the parts department for the dealer for that brand of vehicle and they'll sell you a connector with wire tails already in it.

Comment: Go to a scrap yard and find the same vehicle or another that uses the same fuel / brake or whatever system Bosch, Delphi etc

Comment: Looking very BMWish.

Comment: That is a custom connector designed for the automotive manufacturer.